# Display Excel account username in a cell on open

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

Working with *Office 2013*, I am trying to insert VBA code to automatically enter the employee name as it is displayed in the top right hand corner of any Office product into cell `B2` upon them opening up the excel spreadsheet.  The current code I am using is

```
Sub Auto_Open()

    Range("B2").Value = " " & Application.UserName

End Sub
```

However, this just makes it display "Authorized User".
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Would the username work? `Range("B2").Value = VBA.Environ("username")`.

Comment: No that one gives me an employee ID number.

Comment: I found this resource: [http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=768](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=768)

Comment: Please open a command windows (Windows Key+R then `cmd.exe`) and then type `SET` this will display all the environment variables.  Then access the one you want as BruceWayne says with `VBA.Environ()`.  I'm surprised `Username` does not give sensible results, that is a break of convention.

Comment: @SMeaden - Hm, looking in to this it looks like he doesn't actually want an Environment variable (I think).  It looks like he's trying to pull the current Office User's full name, as given in the User Login information, if that makes sense?  My username environment variable is `bwayne`, but looking in Office, the Login/subscription info gives my full name, `Bruce Wayne // bwayne@bw.com // Switch Account`.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR8AH.jpg).  How can we get *that* info?

Comment: @BruceWayne: I don't have that, is that a subscription based licence?  I pay outright.

Comment: Hm odd, if I use `user = Application.UserName`, I get my `Bruce Wayne` returned. What name is showing in Office for you? `John Doe` and `...UserName` is returning `Authorized User`?

Comment: @SMeaden - Yeah, we have the subscription one.  It doesn't seem to matter though, as my new comment states, it does indeed look like the Environment variables should work. Hmm.

Comment: Yeah that does not work.  Only my ID appears in all of the variables.  And mine is subscription based.

Comment: I use `Application.Parent.UserName` - which at my work grabs the novell user login name. This might be useless, but I'm curious what you get by using the parent.

Comment: `Application.Username` should do the trick. I think it has something to do with the type of subscription you have but just the same your code *should* work. It works perfect at my end.

Answer (score 2):

I poked around at this morning. I figured this information must be stored *somewhere* in the registry if it isn't accessible as part of the Excel object model. This makes sense, especially if this username is part of a corporate subscription.

---

**The Registry Key**

I did a search in the registry for how my username showed up in Excel, and this popped up.

[image: Registry Snip]

The `FriendlyName` is exactly how my username shows up in Excel. So all we need now is a method to read this registry key's `FriendlyName`, and that should do it :)

---

**Code**

Here is some code that works for me based on the location of this key. It may be slightly different on your computer, so you *may* need to tweak this to find the `FriendlyName`

```
Private Function GetFriendlyName() As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    Const ComputerName As String = "."

    Dim CPU                 As Object
    Dim RegistryKeyPath     As String
    Dim RegistrySubKeys()   As Variant
    Dim RegistryValues()    As Variant
    Dim SubKeyName          As Variant
    Dim SubKeyValue         As Variant
    Dim KeyPath             As String

    GetFriendlyName = vbNullString

    Set CPU = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & ComputerName & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    'Specify where to look
    RegistryKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Common\Identity\Identities"

    'Enumerate the registry keys
    CPU.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, RegistryKeyPath, RegistrySubKeys

    'Iterate each key in the identities folder
    For Each SubKeyName In RegistrySubKeys

        'Get each value in that folder
        CPU.EnumValues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, RegistryKeyPath & "\" & SubKeyName, RegistryValues

        'Go through each value, and find the Friendly Name
        For Each SubKeyValue In RegistryValues

            If SubKeyValue = "FriendlyName" Then
                KeyPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\" & RegistryKeyPath & "\" & SubKeyName & "\" & SubKeyValue

                'Read the key
                With CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
                    GetFriendlyName = .RegRead(KeyPath)
                End With

                Exit Function
            End If

        Next

    Next

CleanExit:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    'Handle errors here
    Resume CleanExit
End Function

'Run this to see the output in the immediate window
Private Sub ExampleUsage()
    Debug.Print "The friendly name is: " & GetFriendlyName
End Sub
```

---

**Results**

```
The friendly name is: Ryan A. Wildry
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Dim Username As String
Dim path As String
Dim sourcefile As String
Dim objFso As FileSystemObject

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFso.FileExists(path & " ~$" & sourcefile) Then
    Username = Split(GetFileOwner(path, " ~$" & sourcefile), "\")(1)
    Range("B2").Value = " " & Username
Else
    MsgBox ("File not Found!")
End If
End Sub
```